# java create list of objects from json string with jackson. Error: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I have JSON string which contains a list of objects:

```
[
  {title: title1,id: 1,children: [
              {title: title1_1,id: 1_1,children: [
                   {title: title1_1_1,id: 1_1_1,children: []},
                   {title: title1_1_2,id: 1_1_2,children: []}
              ]}
   ]},
   {title: title2,id: 2,children: [
        {title: title2_1,id: 2_2,children: []}
   ]}
 ]
```

I would like to create list of Objects in java from this json string from above.

Can I do this with jsonMapper read method from Jackson package?

Can You give me some examples?

-- Edit --

here is my class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="procedure__SkeletonElement")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
public abstract class SkeletonElement extends GenericHierarchicalModel<SkeletonElement> {
    @Transient
    public String getDecriminatorValue() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
    @Override
    public String toJson() {
        return "{\"title\":\"" + this.getName() + "\", \"id\":\"" + this.getId() + "\", \"type\":\"" + this.getDecriminatorValue() + "\", \"children\": [" + listToJson(this.getChildren()) + "]}";
    }
    public SkeletonElement toObject(String jsonObject) {
        System.out.println("dedicated method");
        ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            //GenericModel<T> t = jsonMapper.readValue(jsonObject, GenericModel.class);
            SkeletonElement skeletonElement = jsonMapper.readValue(jsonObject, SkeletonElement.class);
            //return t;
            return skeletonElement;
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and the class that is extended:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GenericHierarchicalModel<T extends GenericHierarchicalModel<T>> extends GenericModel<T> {
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private T parent;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<T> children;

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public T getParent() {return parent;}
    public void setParent(T parent) {this.parent = parent;}
    public List<T> getChildren() {return children;}
    public void setChildren(List<T> children) {this.children = children;}

    @Override
    public String toJson() {
        return "{\"title\":\"" + this.name + "\", \"id\":\"" + this.getId() + "\", \"children\": [" + listToJson(this.getChildren()) + "]}";
    }
    public String listToJson(List<T> children) {
        String json = "";
        for(int i=0; i<children.size(); i++) {
            json = json + children.get(i).toJson();
            if(children.size()!=i+1) {
                json = json + ", ";
            }
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

current error that occur:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.derp.procedure.model.SkeletonElement, problem: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@6e927a3a; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: some. added java method in body post

Comment: I am asking is it even possible. Or should I start implementing my own string parser? It is quite complicated structure. Elements are self related.

Comment: Your signature should look more like this: `public <T> T toObject(String jsonObject)`

Comment: Unfortunatelly it dosnt work. Error: `Can not construct instance of com.derp.generic.model.GenericModel, problem: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information`