# Gson deserialize list of self nested elements. Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Tags: nested, gson, deserialization, self-reference

I am trying to deserialize JSON object. It is quite complecated cause, the json i actual a list of objects that are self related (one element can have many children)

I use method:

```
public List<SkeletonElement> toObject(String jsonObject) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<SkeletonElement> list = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, new TypeToken<List<SkeletonElement>>(){}.getType());
    return list;
}
```

where `String jsonObject` is:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Faza przygotowawcza",
        "id": "1",
        "type": "SkeletonJobElement",
        "parent_id": "null",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Uzyskaj dane kontaktowe klienta",
                "id": "2",
                "type": "SkeletonJobElement",
                "parent_id": "1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Wizytówka klienta",
                        "id": "5",
                        "type": "SkeletonFileElement",
                        "parent_id": "2",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Ankieta- Dane klienta",
                        "id": "6",
                        "type": "SkeletonFileElement",
                        "parent_id": "2",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Faza realizacji",
        "id": "3",
        "type": "SkeletonJobElement",
        "parent_id": "null",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Wprowadź klienta do systemu",
                "id": "4",
                "type": "SkeletonJobElement",
                "parent_id": "3",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But unfortunatelly I am getting an error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/derp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 72 path $[0].parent] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 72 path $[0].parent
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:387)
```

and the whole stack trace:

```
gru 21, 2014 2:07:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/derp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 72 path $[0].parent] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 72 path $[0].parent
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:387)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:189)
    at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.read(Gson.java:892)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
    at com.derp.procedure.model.SkeletonElement.toObject(SkeletonElement.java:44)
    at com.derp.procedure.model.Skeleton.setSkeletonElements(Skeleton.java:54)
    at com.derp.procedure.controller.ProcedureController.elementsAssignmentSubmit(ProcedureController.java:83)
    at com.derp.procedure.controller.ProcedureController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$35de90ba.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:266)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at com.derp.procedure.controller.ProcedureController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$75d0c7fc.elementsAssignmentSubmit(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:879)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:146)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:279)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I now that the problem occur cause I am giving only id of parent element instead of whole object. But I would like to do not repeat objects it there is no need.

All of the related elements (children, parents) are in this list of json objects. I would like gson use this id to find object in json string and applied it.

More code of mine releated to this issue is in this post:
[Gson deserialize json. java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public com.derp.procedure.model.SkeletonElement() with no args] with root cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572831/gson-deserialize-json-java-lang-runtimeexception-failed-to-invoke-public-com-d)

Can anyone help me?